# Why does installing a device driver from a virtual drive fail in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, virtual-drive

I have a driver that needs to be installed from a virtual drive. I am able to install this driver (*.sys) from the normal directory, but when I try to install it from a virtual drive it does not happen. Is there any constraint on installing Windows device drivers from virtual drives?

I think installing drivers from virtual drives on Windows XP is possible.

I am using Windows 7, both x86 and x64 versions.

Comment: What do you mean by "virtual drive"? To my knowledge, Windows doesn't have virtual drive support built in like other operating systems. It requires third-party software.

Comment: Hi Cody Gray, I have a third party application to create the virtual drive. The problem I have is I am unable to install a driver from this virtual drive but I am able to install the driver successfully from physical drive like C:\ or D:\. The driver is installed automatically by a software and we do not need to do anything manually.

Comment: How are you installing the driver for this drive?

Comment: I have a software application that launches a 3rd party program which in-turn reads the files from a virtual driver and installs them. One of these files is a device driver (*.sys) which this 3rd party program is unable to install from a virtual drive, but able to install from the physical drive like C:, D: etc.  So unfortunately I do not have any log files from this program nor any from the OS itself, I was said. But one thing that is strikingly posing as the probable issue is the location from where the driver is being installed from - a virtual drive.

Comment: depending on how the drive is presented to the system, the OS can treat this drive as remote and thus having more strict security settings. There's not much you can do besides contacting the vendor of 3rd party program.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using two different bit versions of windows from your actual windows and your virtual machine. Say that in your virtual machine is windows x64 and your actual windows is x86. The 64 bit version of the driver would not be compatible with the 32 bit version of windows.

Comment: Hi Johannes, sorry I should have been clearer. I have two file versions of the driver x86 and x64. You can take that I am using x86. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

After a hell lot of effort, I found that Antivirus is the issue. The setup should not give any error while installing. Please run as administrator when you run the setup and turn off antivirus if any.

Turning vmci0 value to false is not at all a good approach